# new "Metier" is created when editing a "Metier "

Tags: laravel

when I try to edit a "Metier", a new "Metier" is created and the old one stays the same. I want to crush the old "Metier" and create a new one by mediting.

**Controller**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $metier=Metier::find($id);
    return view('metier.edit',['libelle_metier'=>$metier]);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $metier=Metier::find($id);
    return view('metier.edit',['libelle_metier'=>$metier]);
}
```

**view**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">libelle Metier </label>
    <input type="text"  name ="libelle_metier" class="form-control"value ="{{$libelle_metier->libelle_metier}}" >
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value = "enregistrer" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see your update method is taking the user to edit form again, here is a good resource controller (MetierController) you can use.

> This is just a sample to give an idea. To make it good there is a lot
>   more that can be done, like validations, exceptions and good
>   redirections.

**MetierController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Metier;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MetierController extends Controller
{
    //inject the model to constructor
    public function __construct(Metier $metier)
    {
        $this->metier = $metier;
    }

    //takes user to creation form
    // GET 
    public function create()
    {
        return view('metier.create');
    }  

    //when the create form is submitted
    // POST
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //some validations
        //if the form field matches with db fields you can use $request->all()
        $metier = $this->metier->create($request->all());

        //assuming you have route names set
        return redirect()->route('metier.show',$metier->id);
    }

    //takes user to edit form
    // GET
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $metier = $this->metier->find($id);
        return view('metier.edit',compact('metier'));
    }

    //when the edit form is sublitted
    // PATCH(POST)
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $metier = $this->metier->find($id);
        //some validations
        //if the form field matches with db fields you can use $request->all()
        $metier->update($request->all());
        //take user to somewhere when the update is done
        return view('metier.edit',compact('metier'));
    }

 }
```

Comment: Looks good; Only suggestion I would make is don't return a `view()` in a `POST` function return; use `redirect()` (like you did in `store`). If you return a view, and the user refreshes the page, it can attempt the `POST` request again.